# org-mode #+SETUPFILE not working with properties drawer

Tags: org-mode

Give this file

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :var A="this is a"
:END:

#+begin_src sh
echo ${A}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: this is a
```

I would like to move the properties drawer to a separate file and import it into the main one. To do so I'm using the `#SETUPFILE` property suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59059/36590), but this doesn't seem to work.

***main.org***

```
#+SETUPFILE: test.org

#+begin_src sh
echo ${A}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

***test.org***

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :var A="this is a"
:END:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `test.org` instead:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sh: :var A="this is a"
```

Comment: This is also not working for me

Comment: You may have found a bug. `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Removing the colon after sh seems to make it work. Found this example in the org info: "#+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session *R*".